# PUT method form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the following to try and set a PUT method on the form but it is still doing a post. I have referred to the docs and it seems like im doing this right.

```
form_for @firm, html: {autocomplete: "off"}, url: firm_path, method: :put do |f|
...
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It does this because browsers don't support `PUT`/`DELETE` very well. You can read more about this in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-put-or-delete-methods-work):

> However, most browsers *don’t support* methods other than “GET” and
>   “POST” when it comes to submitting forms.
>
> Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST
>   with a hidden input named `"_method"`, which is set to reflect the
>   desired method.

Comment: Yes but as within the API docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) passing the :method hash on the form for should automagically add that additionally field.

Comment: In fact the issue is that form_for is NOT adding the hidden field

Comment: @JasonWaldrip Now *that* just doesn't make any sense at all—are you sure it's not there?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I reloaded the app and it appeared. Very strange!

Comment: @JasonWaldrip Weird. Glad it's working though. (Perhaps you had modified your routes? Doing so requires restarting I believe.)