# Rails 6.1 form_with doesn't send PUT request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for, form-with

I added the `method: patch` to the `form_with` helper [(like it said to in this SO post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551330/put-method-form-for)

```
<%= form_with(model: [:admin, contest], method: :patch) do |form| %>
  ...
```

and the `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">` shows up (like it's supposed to) but then when I click "Submit", the request is still a POST request and I get the error

```
No route matches [POST] "/admin/contests/7"
```

Comment: May be this request from JS?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and resolved it by changing it to:

```
method: "patch"
```

Update: You're right, "patch" and :patch do the same. I also added the url from my routes file:

```
model#update
```

I think I need some more info. What does your controller look like? What model is it? Have you tried specifying the model and the url in form_with?

Comment: wait `:patch` and `patch` result in the same thing for me, both add the hidden form input

Comment: It doesn't matter. `"patch"` and `:patch` will work the same way